# Ignore git log cross-branch duplicates

Tags: git, git-log

If I perform `git log -g`, for instance, the results will include many commits containing the same content (for example, commits with the same diff but cherry picked to different branches). How can I have git log only show one of those commits and ignore others with duplicate diff content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need the `--cherry-pick` option. In my test:

```
 git log -g --format="%h %s %b"
 3301841 improve readme (cherry picked from commit ...)
 731e382 test
 613e970 improve readme
```

With `--cherry-pick`, I only get the 3301841.

> --cherry-pick Omit any commit that introduces the same change as another commit on the “other side” when the set of commits are limited with symmetric difference.